# Как вывести русские символы в haskell

Tags: windows, haskell

Пробую запустить простую программу на Haskell

```
main = print "Привет, мир!"
```

Но при выводе получаю:

```
C:\haskell>runhaskell helloWorld.hs
"\1055\1088\1080\1074\1077\1090, \1084\1080\1088!"
```

Как настроить нормальный вывод кириллицы?

Answer (score 2):

В общем, насколько я понял [надо использовать](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2840126/5752652) не print а putStrLn:

```
main = putStrLn "Привет, мир!"
```

Comment: Даже без кириллицы кавычки никуда бы не делись